# Automapper: Mapper.Map does not work in every build

Tags: c#, automapper

I have very strange issue with `AutoMapper`

In my windows service, When I create mapping from `IDataReader` to `List object`, it works for very first time only when i run the service.

As soon as I stop the service and run it again, AutoMapper cannot able to Map. Below is my code:

**Property Class**

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

**Actual Implementation**

```
var employeeData = DataHelper.ExecuteReader("Select Id, Name, Number from dbo.Employee");
var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees = employeeData.MapToList<List<Employee>>();
```

**Generic Extension Method**

```
public static T MapToList<T>(this DataTable reader) where T : class
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, T>();
    //  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return Mapper.Map<IDataReader, T>(reader.CreateDataReader());
}
```

Apart from this, I have noticed that when I clean solution and run service again it starts working.

I am not able to Identify why it behaves like this.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please post the error message and stack trace.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: No I am not getting any error. But it cannot able to map to list object. and when I use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`, it shows that no property has been mapped. and when i clean and rebuild solution, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given your table's fields have the same name as `Employee`'s properties,  you should be able to do like this (without any explicit mapping config):

```
var employeeData = DataHelper.ExecuteReader("Select Id, Name, Number from dbo.Employee");
var employees = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Employee>>(employeeData.CreateDataReader());
```

Comment: Updated answer, see above.

Comment: @user2988458 You mean it works the first time but not when you restart the service?

Comment: Yes. If there is an issue in my mapping than it should not work for first time as well.

Comment: @user2988458 I suggest you do the mapping by hand without AutoMapper and see if it works as expected.

Comment: @user2988458 OK. You could try calling `Mapper.Reset()` before `CreateMap`

Comment: I have tried that also. But still no luck. I think this is an issue regarding race condition